# Getting from Macau to Zhuhai Airport

Tags: china, macau, zuh

I am planning a trip to Macau, then to somewhere in Mainland China. I saw that flights from Zhuhai to Mainland China are cheaper than flights from Macau or Hong Kong to the same places. I have the necessary documents to enter both Mainland China and Hong Kong/Macau. The problem is with getting to Zhuhai Airport from Macau.

I saw, in my research, that there are two border crossings between Macau and Zhuhai: Gongbei Port (拱北口岸) and Hengqin Port (横琴口岸). Gongbei port looks to be really busy during the day, so that seems out of the question, as I am in a rush (only half a day in Macau). After further consultation of the sources, I stumbled upon this from [this source](http://www.chinahighlights.com/travelguide/transportation/guangzhou-zhuhai-macau.htm):

> Hengqin Port - Connecting southern Zhuhai with Cotai, this port is a little out of the way from onward transportation on the mainland. However, it provides an extremely quick crossing and easy access to, or from, the Macau airport. **Open 24 hours a day**.

My questions are:

- Do any connections exist between Hengqin Port and Zhuhai Airport? Do
  I have to take a taxi, or does public transportation exist? Maybe
  there's a subway in Zhuhai? (My sources say no, but I'm having
  trouble finding up-to-date information on this topic)
- Is the HKMZ bridge a feasible option (feasible meaning doable
  within the span of 3-5 hours)?
- How long of a wait is it to pass customs and immigration at the
  ports?

English is not my first language, so please excuse me if any spelling or grammar mistakes were made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first and second questions, you would actually be better off taking the airport bus from Macau.

According to the website of [Zhuhai Airport](http://www.zhairport.com/content/details_15_2113188.html), there is a shuttle bus that stops at the The Venetian and Studio City hotels. It costs 100 yuan per person and takes around 80 minutes.

If you have WeChat, you can buy the tickets through the account called 'Zhuhai Airport Express'. If not, you can buy them from the cross-border bus ticket counter at Studio City.